# How can I split a string into chunks of 1024 with iterator and string_view

Tags: c++

I want to split a string into chunks of 1024 just like this.

```
std::string content;
std::vector<std::string_view>
data{_iterator<std::string>{content, 1024},
     _iterator<std::string>{}};
```

It's graceful and efficient, but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Why do you have to use iterators? Why not the string directly like `content.data()` to `content.data() + 1023` for the first view?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude just thought it would be intuitive

Comment: and more c++-style

Comment: From C++20 `std::string_view` can accept iterators for construction, and `std::string` iterators are random-access iterators, `std::begin(content)` to `std::begin(content) + 1024`? Of course care must be take to make sure that `std::end(content)` isn't passed (but that must be taken into account with using the pointers as well).

Answer (score 3):

Probably not as elegant as you want, but try something like this:

```cpp
std::string content = ...;
std::vector<std::string_view> data;

if (!content.empty())
{
    data.reserve((content.size() + 1023) / 1024);

    std::string_view content_view = content;
    size_t i = 0;

    do
    {
        data.push_back(content_view.substr(i, 1024));
        i += data.back().size();
    }
    while (i < content.size());
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
std::string content = ...;
std::vector<std::string_view> data;

if (!content.emoty())
{
    data.reserve((content.size() + 1023) / 1024);

    const char* ptr = content.c_str();
    size_t size = content.size();

    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i += 1024) {
        data.emplace_back(ptr+i, std::min(size-i, 1024));
    }
}
```

If you really want to initialize the `vector` using chunk-sized iterators, you will have to write you own iterator class from scratch to handle that.  There is no standard iterator class that will iterate a string (or any other container) in chunks of N elements.

Comment: cppreference says `Returns a view of the substring [pos, pos + rcount), where rcount is the smaller of count and size() - pos.` So I guess you don't need to reserve?

Comment: @hxb the `reserve()` is pre-allocating the `vector`'s internal array so it doesn't have to reallocate the array while `std::string_view` objects are being pushed into it. It has nothing to do with how the individual `std::string_view` objects are created. The code is `reserve()`'ing space for 1 `std::string_view` object per 1024 `char`s in `content`. Up to 1024 `char`s = 1 `std::string_view`, up to 2048 `chars` = 2 std::string_view`s, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way I can think of now.

```
std::string_view data = content;
std::vector<std::string_view> chunks;
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i += 1024)
    chunks.push_back(data.substr(i, 1024));
```

Comment: You should `reserve()` the `vector` before entering the loop, since you can easily calculate up front how many `string_view`s will be pushed into it.

Answer (score 0):

With C++23, this can be written very elegantly:

```cpp
#include <ranges>

auto data = content
            | std::views::chunk(1024)
            | std::ranges::to<std::vector<std::string>>();
```

For reasons I can't figure out, I can't make this work with `std::vector<std::string_view>`.